Pythonanywhere and flask app requiring Playwright, does not install
I have a Flask app that uses crawl4ai, which has a dependancy on Playwright, listed here, despite not directly interacting with the browser object, we still need to install Playwright:
https://crawl4ai.com/mkdocs/basic/installation/
Pythonanywhere however, say this is not possible, and the only workaround I can find is about directly using their browser version pre-installed:
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Playwright/
The next step would normally to install the browsers using playwright install. However, that won't work on PythonAnywhere
This is not a help because i'm interacting with crawl4ai, not the Playwright browser.
What are my options here since I want to use crawl4ai and it has a dependancy that I simply cannot install?  Do I need to find another python provider?

Have you read the rest of the help page? It literally gives you a workaround if you can't run playwright install.

@BcK i literally said why i can't do that, that code is meaningless because my code uses crawl4ai

I thought crawl4ai was passing kwargs (such as the executable browser path) to the underlying playwright, but apparently that's not the case. You might go for a hacky way, but that wouldn't be pleasant. Maybe like you said, you should look for another provider.

@BcK ok thx for looking at it
